# Translating from WSO2 to camel with Java DSL: How to forward with URI pattern

Tags: java, routes, wso2, apache-camel

I'm removing WSO2 from our stack and I have to write in Camel Java DSL the endpoints that were implemented in WSO2.

In WSO2 we had an endpoint as below:

```
<resource methods="OPTIONS GET" uri-template="/request/{data}" inSequence="requestreset"/>
<http method="GET" uri-template="http://127.0.0.1/index.php?_q=requestreset&amp;data={uri.var.data}"/>
```

My code in Java Camel's Router is:

```
public class DefaultRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private HashMap<String, String> routeCorresponding = new HashMap();

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        routeCorresponding.put("reset/request/{data}", "http://127.0.0.1/index.php?_q=requestreset&data={data}");

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : routeCorresponding.entrySet()) {
            String url = pair.getKey();
            String target = pair.getValue();

            String resultTarget = target.contains("?") ? target + "&bridgeEndpoint=true" : target + "?bridgeEndpoint=true";

            fromF("servlet:"+ url +"?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                    .log("Request: ${in.header."+ Exchange.HTTP_METHOD +"} to ${in.header."+ Exchange.HTTP_URI +"}")
                    .toF(resultTarget);
        }

    }

}
```

But it doesn't work as I would want it because when I make a request to `tomcat.myserver.com:8080/camel-example-servlet/reset/request/blablablablabla` I get a response this:
`org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://127.0.0.1/index.php/reset/request/blablablablabla?_q=requestreset&data=%7Bdata%7D with statusCode: 404`

Instead of `http://127.0.0.1/index.php/reset/request/blablablablabla?_q=requestreset&data=%7Bdata%7D`, I would like the following request to be on `http://127.0.0.1/index.php?_q=requestreset&data=blablablablabla`

Is it possible to achieve in Camel/Java DSL that? Basically what WSO2 was implementing with the URI template and the curly brackets around fields?

Comment: Feel free to edit my post to correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely achieve that - but your `{data}` block is stored as a header, so you need to [refer to it as `${header.data}` in your target URI](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simple-language.html).

Here's an example using [the REST DSL](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html):

```java
restConfiguration().component("servlet");

rest("/reset/request/{data}")
    .get()
    .route()
    .log("Received request...")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, simple("/index.php"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("_q=requestreset&data=${header.data}"))
    .to("http://localhost:8080?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

**Edit** based on your question below. Alternatively, if you need to proxy hundreds of URLs, instead of creating hundreds of routes, you could just create one single route which proxies them all and implement your routing logic in a [Processor](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/process-eip.html), e.g.:

```java
from("servlet:?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
            // set your target URI here, look it up from the HashMap, etc.
        }
    })
    .to("http://localhost:8080?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

Comment: Is it possible to allow get and post requests on the same endpoint? Or what would be the best way to implement endpoints that accept either GET or POST requests in the for loop considering `routeCorresponding` HashMap can contain hundreds of them?

Comment: I think you need to define each HTTP verb separately using the REST DSL. As for your second question, I've added another bit to my answer above.